# ProgressBar duration and hasEnded methods

Tags: java, android

I'm working with a progress bar and an animation.

```
        progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        Animation animation = new RotateAnimation(30, 180);
        progressBar.setAnimation(animation);
```

further down in my method I

set the duration for this animation

`progressBar.getAnimation().setDuration(3000);`

so for 3 seconds, the animation will run.

if I want to hide the ProgressBar after the animation ends I have to do the following

```
if(progressBar.getAnimation().getDuration() == 3000){
            progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
        }
```

What I tried doing was

```
if(progressBar.getAnimation.hasEnded()){
 progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
}
```

this does not work

Could somebody explain why the `hasEnded` method doesn't seem to return `true` where I think it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can call set an Animation Listener on the animation object. The Listener calls tree methods, one of which is onAnimationEnd().

```
animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
       @Override
       public void onAnimationStart(Animation anim) {
       };
       @Override
       public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation anim) {
       };
       @Override
       public void onAnimationEnd(Animation anim)  {
          // here your logic                 
       };
});
```

Comment: This DOES work.

Thank's.. but I'm now just curious : )

Why doesn't the method `hasEnded` work the way I used it in the `if` statement?

Eitherway, I will accept your answer.

Comment: I mean, it should implies that hasEnded is somehow blocking, waiting for the animation to end. And it is not the case

Comment: I had a brain fart so I didn't get it right away. But now it makes sense.

It just checks if it finished. Derp. :p

Answer (score 1):

I think problem is in below line...

```
if(progressBar.getAnimation.hasEnded()) {
```

it should be...

```
if(progressBar.getAnimation().hasEnded()) {
```

Edit::

That's because you're starting the animation and immediately checking if the animation has ended which is doubtful unless it simply doesn't do anything. What you want to do is implement an [AnimationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html) callback and set it to that animation.

Comment: My code is actually `if(progressBar.getAnimation().hasEnded()){
}`

that was just a spelling error on my part.

Comment: ok...i saw that syntax error in your question that's why i have corrected it.

Comment: I see what you're saying. 
My question now, I suppose, is why does it then work if I set it as 

`if(progressBar.getAnimation().getDuration == 3000){ .. }`

Going by your logic, shouldn't the same happen to the 3000 millisecond check? Shouldn't it check "is it 3000" and then not return true.

What seems to happen is it wait's for the 3000 milliseconds and then performs the logic when the criteria is met.. but it won't do it with `hasEnded`.

Comment: `getDuration()` just return the duration of animation which you have set previously by `setDuration()` method.... In your case you have set duration of 3000 ms. So, `getDuration()` will return 3000, that's why it become equal & if condition becomes true in that case.